# Tighter tail bounds for subgaussian random variables

Tags: probability, gaussian-integral, distribution-tails, orlicz-spaces

> Let $X$ be a random variable on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{tX}\right] \leq e^{t^2/2}$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. What is the best *explicit* upper bound we can give on $\mathbb{P}[X \geq x]$ for $x > 0$?

A well-known upper bound can be obtained by applying Markov's inequality to the moment generating function of X: For $t>0$, $$\mathbb{P}[X \geq x] = \mathbb{P}\left[e^{tX}\geq e^{tx}\right] \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[e^{tX}\right]}{e^{tx}} \leq e^{t^2/2-tx}.$$ Setting $t=x$, yields $$\mathbb{P}[X \geq x] \leq e^{-x^2/2}.$$
**How tight is this?**

Examples of such $X$ include the standard Gaussian and Rademacher distributions. Both satisfy stronger tail bounds, as illustrated by the following plot. This makes me wonder whether stronger bounds hold for all such $X$.

[image]

Some more precise questions:

> Define $$f(x) = \sup \left\{ \mathbb{P}[X\geq x] : X \text{ a random variable satisfying } \mathbb{E}\left[e^{tX}\right] \leq e^{t^2/2} \text{ for all } t \in \mathbb{R} \right\}.$$
>
> - What is $f(1)$?
>
>   (We know $f(1) \in \left[\frac12,e^{-1/2}\right]$, by the Rademacher example and the above tail bound.)
>
>   What is $\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) \cdot e^{x^2/2}$?
>
>   (We know it is $\leq 1$, by the above tail bound.)
>
>   What is $\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) \cdot e^{x^2/2} \cdot {x}$?
>
>   (We know it is $\geq 1/\sqrt{2\pi}$, by the Gaussian example [[link]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.2063v3.pdf).)

Any improved bounds on $f$ would interest me. Is there a closed form expression for $f$? or some way to numerically approximate $f$?

A follow-up question would be: Are there are any *natural assumptions* that in addition to subgaussianity would imply $\mathbb{P}[X \ge x] \le O\left(\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x}\right)$.

Comment: $0$. The bound is trivially not tight (just think of where Markov's inequality comes from) but it is exponentially tight: $\liminf_{x\to\infty} \frac{-\log S(x)}{x^2/2}\ge 1$. $1.$ $f(1)=\frac 1 2$. $2.$ $\limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{\bar\Phi(x)}=1$.

Comment: On $[0,1]$, $f(t)=\frac 1 {1+t}$ with equality reached for an obvious 2- point distribtuion,

Answer (score 2):

Consider a r.v. $X$ with distribution function $F(x) = (1 - e^{-\frac{x^2}2})I_{x \ge 0}$. Then $E e^{tX} \le \sqrt{2 \pi} e^{\frac{t^2}2} $ and condition $P(X \ge x) = e^{-\frac{x^2}2}$ holds for all $x \ge 0$. It's not a solution of the problem, but it shows that the estimate $ e^{-\frac{x^2}2}$ looks like a rather sharp  estimate.

Comment: Is this really true? Mathematica gives the mgf. of your distribution as $\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{\frac{t^2}{2}} t \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+1\right)+1\sim \sqrt{2\pi}\,t\,e^{t^2/2}$. This looks suspiciously like we are "shooting over" by a polynomial factor again.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Saddlepoint approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddlepoint_approximation_method) you can typically improve the bounds to be as sharp as you want.

If the moment generating function of a distribution is written as $M(t)$ and the cumulant generating function as $K(t) = \log(M(t))$ then the saddlepoint approximation to the PDF of a distribution is defined as:
$$\hat{f}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi K''(\hat{s})}} \exp(K(\hat{s}) - \hat{s}x)$$

You should also check out [Exponential tilting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_tilting) as a more general method for getting "medium deviations" bounds.